# How to perform case-insensitive aggregation grouping in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say that I want to aggregate and group by documents in MongoDb by the `Description` field.

Running the following (case-sensitive by default):

```
db['Products'].aggregate(
    { $group: { 
        _id: { 'Description': "$Description" },
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        docs: { $push: "$_id" }
    }},
    { $match: {
        count: { $gt : 1 }
    }}
);
```

on my sample data gives me 1000 results, which is fine.

But now I expect that running a ***case-insensitive*** query (using `$toLower`) should give me less than or equal to 1000 results:

```
db['Products'].aggregate(
    { $group: { 
        _id: { 'Description': {$toLower: "$Description"} },
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        docs: { $push: "$_id" }
    }},
    { $match: {
        count: { $gt : 1 }
    }}
);
```

But instead I get more than 1000 results. That can't be right, can it? More common entries should get grouped together to yield less number of total groupings ... I think.

So then probably my aggregation query is wrong! Which brings me to my question:

How should case-insensitive aggregation grouping in MongoDb be performed?

Comment: If you think there is a problem then you need to ask in a way that reproduces the problem. So you should be able to show a small dataset in which `$toLower` does not have the desired effect. This process typically has two outcomes. 1. Shows a real bug in a reproducible way. 2. Actually highlights something else is the problem that you did not think was a problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which BTW is essentially all the same concepts as unit testing. Needs to be reproducible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You approach to case-insensitive grouping is correct so perhaps your observation is not? ;)

Try this example:

```
// insert two documents
db.getCollection('test').insertOne({"name" : "Test"}) // uppercase 'T'
db.getCollection('test').insertOne({"name" : "test"}) // lowercase 't'

// perform the grouping
db.getCollection('test').aggregate({ $group: { "_id": { $toLower: "$name" }, "count": { $sum: 1 } } }) // case insensitive
db.getCollection('test').aggregate({ $group: { "_id": "$name", "count": { $sum: 1 } } }) // case sensitive
```

You may have a typo somewhere?

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/#behavior) also states that

> $toLower only has a well-defined behavior for strings of ASCII characters.

Perhaps that's what's biting you here?

Comment: Thanks @dnickless ...I fear there is something interesting in my data that's causing this assumption to fall flat on its face ... some sort of cornercase perhaps ... I guess without sharing that data for others to have the same WTF moment, this won't become a meaningful question :/

Comment: It worked like a charm, but how do I return to the correct text? Must I aggregate like this and add the string as another field in the results to maintain the original string?

Comment: @GuilhermeSampaio, not sure what you're asking here. Perhaps a new SO question would be helpful.